# NTP Server - sync from local system clock

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian, ntp, ntpd

I need to create device (currently Raspberry Pi 3 based) which states as NTP Server, it has no connection to Internet and NTP should read actual time from local system clock (this clock is set from application). My /etc/ntp.conf is:

```
restrict default kod nomodify notrap nopeer noquery
restrict -6 default kod nomodify notrap nopeer noquery

restrict 127.0.0.1
restrict -6 ::1
restrict ::1

server  127.127.1.0 # local clock
fudge   127.127.1.0 stratum 1

driftfile /var/lib/ntp/ntp.drift
logfile /var/log/ntp.log
```

When testing connection (after `service ntp restart`) with `ntpdate -du localhost` command I get this output:

```
transmit(::1)
receive(::1)
transmit(127.0.0.1)
receive(127.0.0.1)
transmit(::1)
receive(::1)
transmit(127.0.0.1)
receive(127.0.0.1)
transmit(::1)
receive(::1)
transmit(127.0.0.1)
receive(127.0.0.1)
transmit(::1)
receive(::1)
transmit(127.0.0.1)
receive(127.0.0.1)
::1: Server dropped: strata too high
127.0.0.1: Server dropped: strata too high
server ::1, port 123
stratum 16, precision -20, leap 11, trust 000
refid [::1], delay 0.02573, dispersion 0.00000
transmitted 4, in filter 4
reference time:    00000000.00000000  Thu, Feb  7 2036  6:28:16.000
originate timestamp: ddbf0da9.473a860b  Tue, Nov 21 2017 20:40:09.278
transmit timestamp:  ddbf0da9.47320583  Tue, Nov 21 2017 20:40:09.278
filter delay:  0.02579  0.02573  0.02574  0.02573
         0.00000  0.00000  0.00000  0.00000
filter offset: 0.000018 -0.00001 -0.00000 -0.00001
         0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
delay 0.02573, dispersion 0.00000
offset -0.000011

server 127.0.0.1, port 123
stratum 16, precision -20, leap 11, trust 000
refid [127.0.0.1], delay 0.02570, dispersion 0.00000
transmitted 4, in filter 4
reference time:    00000000.00000000  Thu, Feb  7 2036  6:28:16.000
originate timestamp: ddbf0da9.7a812105  Tue, Nov 21 2017 20:40:09.478
transmit timestamp:  ddbf0da9.7a7990a1  Tue, Nov 21 2017 20:40:09.478
filter delay:  0.02571  0.02570  0.02570  0.02570
         0.00000  0.00000  0.00000  0.00000
filter offset: -0.00000 -0.00001 -0.00001 -0.00001
         0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
delay 0.02570, dispersion 0.00000
offset -0.000013

21 Nov 20:40:09 ntpdate[1181]: no server suitable for synchronization found
```

What am I doing wrong? Why `ntp` does not get time from system clock?

Comment: Hello MarcinZdunek. Please add output of `ntpq -np` to your question so we can see what's going on. Using `ntpdate` for debugging is of little use I'm afraid.

Answer (score 1):

Since the `server` statement does not include the `iburst` keyword, ntpd may take a few minutes to sync with a timesource after it's been restarted. During that time, the answers it gives to other servers are identified as unreliable.

Yes, even when it's effectively syncing with itself.

In the `ntpdate -d` output, the `stratum 16, precision -20, leap 11` means ntpd thinks "I'm not ready to provide time service to any others right now."